# Error in Java application (using Eclipse): "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, hsqldb, classnotfoundexception

I'm using Eclipse to write a Java program that is trying to connect to HSQLDB.

When I try to run the program I get this error:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver`

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where this .jar file lives (somewhere in you /hsqldb/ folder):

`hsqldb.jar`

You then need to add it to your Java project build path like this:

*(This process may vary slightly depending which version of Eclipse you are using):*

1. In Eclipse, right click the relevant project name, click 'Build Path' ->
   'Configure Build Path'
2. Click the 'Libraries' tab
3. Click 'Add External JARs..'
4. Navigate to the folder that contains the hsqldb.jar file, Click
   'Open'
5. Click 'Apply and Close'